# How can a Vue CLI plugin modify transpileDepencies?

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli, babel-loader, webpack-chain

How can my Vue CLI plugin tell babel CLI plugin that a certain dependency in node_modules has to be transpiled?

Even this brute-force attempt failed, though theoretically all files should be transpiled:

```
module.exports = (api, opts) => {
  api.chainWebpack(config => {
    config.module.rules.get('js').exclude.add(_ => false)
```

But replacing `false` with `true` did produce expected results, meaning no files were transpiled.

I suppose the challenge is limited to `js` files, since `vue` files are always transpiled by cli-plugin-babel:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/master/packages/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/index.js#L39